# TypeError: res.writeHead is not a function chapter 6 Fullstack javascript development with MEAN

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeerror

So I'm following along with the Full Stack Javascript development offered by Sitepoint and I've ran into a problem found within chapter 6. I've set up a basic http server which should allow incoming connections.

When I run index.js, I get a log to the console saying it is successfully running at my designated address(127.0.0.1:1337)

As soon as I try to go to that address in my browser it fails to connect and I get this error in my terminal

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined
at Server.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Documents/Git projects/human-resources/index.js:8:26)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at Server.emit (events.js:191:7)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncoming [as onIncoming] (_http_server.js:543:12)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:105:23)
```

It obviously has a problem with this line

```
req.method = req.method.toUpperCase();
```

But I don't know why, I thought maybe if I comment it out it'll work, but when I do that I get a similar error to the above but this time says res.writeHead is not a function

```
TypeError: res.writeHead is not a function
at Server.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Documents/Git projects/human-resources/index.js:12:9)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at Server.emit (events.js:191:7)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncoming [as onIncoming] (_http_server.js:543:12)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:105:23)
```

If anyone could offer some insight into where I or my code is going wrong that would be great my full code is listed below..

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (res,req) {
  //A parsed url to work with in case there are parameters
  var _url;

  //In case the client uses lower case for methods
  req.method = req.method.toUpperCase();
  console.log(req.method + ' ' + req.url);

  if (req.method !== 'GET') {
    res.writeHead(501, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    });

    return res.end(req.method + ' is not implemented by this server');
  }

  if (_url = /^\/employees$/i.exec(req.url)) {
    //return a list of employees
    res.writeHead(200);
    return res.end('employee list');
  } else if (_url = /^\/employees\/(\d+)$/i.exec(req.url)) {
    //find employee by id in the route
    res.writeHead(200);
    return res.end('a single employee');
  } else {
    //try to send the static file
    res.writeHead(200);
    return res.end('static file maybe');
  }

}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');

console.log('Sever Running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have used the request and response in the http.createServer() in the wrong order, I used response then request, should be request and then response like so;

```
http.createServer(function (req,res) {
```

Comment: good one... after resolution I Googled `res.writeHead is not a function` and got your question. anyways good catch :)

Comment: i did that.. it's was working.. and i write new code this time it dosen't work :/